# Dimensionality Reduction of a matrix preserving number of rows

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, principal-component-analysis, singular-value-decomposition

Let A ($d \times k $) be a matrix such that k < d. How to reduce the dimension of the matrix A to another lower dimension matrix B ($d \times l$ ) such that $l < k$. Note that, while reducing the dimension of columns, we want to preserve the number of rows of the original matrix A. The naive technique is the moving average. Is there an intelligent way to preserve number of rows and only reduce the columns by using some other approximation techniques based on truncated SVD/PCA/UMAP/Matrix Decomposition (linear/non-linear) etc.

I understand that by using standard techniques as truncated SVD, if the above matrix A ($d \times k $) gets projected to a lower dimensional space $l$ then the resultant matrix becomes B'($l \times l$ ).